# How do I get the foreign key values of a form in a template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

So Im trying to create a similar panel like django admin and while I have my tables set up with query information and filters, Im trying to copy the "editable" option by creating fields that can be edited in the table. My problem is lets say I have models:

```
class model1(model.Models):
  name = CharField(max_length = 20)
  phone = IntegerField(max_length = 20)
  def __unicode__(self):
     return (#I Just return the name and phone number as a string here)

class model2(model.Models):
  name = ForeignKeyFeild(model1)
  team = CharField(max_length = 20)
```

If I set up a modelformset factory like so in a view:

```
qset = model2.objects.all()
fset = modelformset_factory(model2)
form = fset(queryset = qset)
```

In templates how can I show the value of 'phone' from model1?

When I render the form in the template:

```
{% for f in form %}
  {{f.team.value}} # this gives me the value without an input field
  {{f.name.phone.value}} # this however renders nothing and that's what I'm trying to find out
{%endfor%}
```

Also How can I make it so that `{{f.name.value}}` shows me the unicode string and not the actual numerical value (ID)?

How can I make the {{f.name.phone}} which is information from the table where it holds a foreign_key show?

If not is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original model object is available as the `instance` attribute of the form:

```
{% for f in form %}
    {{ f.instance.team }}
    {{ f.instance.name.phone }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, if you only knew how long I was stuck on this....dude youre a django guru ( I realize youve helped me a few times before)